# Parsing an input files with multiple sentences

Tags: c++

I want to ignore spaces and split any list which are before '':"
my code:

```
string inst,inst_array[32];

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile ("inst.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            getline(myfile,inst);
            for(int j=0; j<inst.length(); j++){
                if(inst[j] == ' ') 
                    inst.erase(j,1);
                inst_array[i]=inst;
            }
            cout<<inst_array[i]<<endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "unable to open file\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

my input file::

```
GG: L.D F1, 4(R4)
    L.D F2, 8(R5)
    ADD.D F4, F6, F2
    SUB.D F5, F7, F1
    MUL.D F6, F1, F5
    ADD.D F7, F2, F6
    ADD.D F6, F1, F7
    DADDI R4, R4, 2
    DADDI R5, R5, 2
    DSUB R1, R1, R2
    BNE R1, R3, GG
    HLT
```

so I want to ignore spaces so that it should be :
L.DF1,4(R4)
LDF2,8(R5) and so on. and also I want to split GG: and want to save in a variable.

what should I do??

Comment: Aside from not having a check for ":" in your code, it looks like you are already doing what you are asking for. Can you explain what part you are struggling with?

Comment: I'd recommend writing an actual lexer for assembly code rather than hacking with removing spaces and such.

Comment: Besides what Mats has said, take a look at regex in C++. You can use regex to build a simple parser that matches the grammar you need.

Comment: I want to split GG: and stor in another variable which is string so that I can access it in future.

Comment: I am able to get without space but only thing I am not able to do is the split of GG: and storing in a variable. please tell me about split.